# How to check qTableWidget for empty cells

Tags: python, pyqt

How to check if qTableWidget has empty cells and if has, turn those empty in 0(zero)?

With this I import data from qtablewidget `table_Level_N` and turn them in array `array`, if `array` has 0 - code execution stops and print out error message in textedit:

```
self.ui.textEdit_status_N.clear()
array = []
for i in range(self.ui.table_Level_N.rowCount()):
    row = []
    array.append(row)
    for j in range(1,6):
        item = self.ui.table_Level_N.item(i,j)
        if item:
            try:
                row.append(float(item.text()))
            except TypeError:
                row.append(0)
         else:
            row.append(0)
if np.all(array):
[some operation]
else: self.ui.textEdit_status_N.append("Error: array has zero")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
except ValueError:
    row.append(0)
```

right after `TypeError`, it will turn all empty cells to 0